# Primefaces: save to db using ajax for inplace tag

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

One more question from me about primefaces (java, jsf).
I have ManagedBean with such code:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AccountManagedBean {
    private Long id = (long) 1;
    private Account account = new Account();
    private AccountJpaController accountController = new AccountJpaController();

    public void AccountManagedBean() {
        extractAccount();
    }

    public void saveAccount() {
       accountController.update(account);
       // extract info for page
       extractAccount();
    }

    public void extractAccount() {
       account = accountController.get(id);
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    } 
}
```

And xhtml file - view part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:body>
        <p:panel id="account">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="column" cellpadding="5">  
                            <h:outputText value="Balance: " />
                            <p:inplace editor="true">  
                                <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{accountManagedBean.saveAccount}" update="account" />
                                <p:inputText value="#{accountManagedBean.account.balance}" required="true"/>  
                            </p:inplace>

                            <h:outputText value="Credit limit: " />
                            <p:inplace editor="true" >
                                <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{accountManagedBean.saveAccount}" update="account" />
                                <p:inputText value="#{accountManagedBean.account.creditLimit}" required="true"/>  
                            </p:inplace>

                            <h:outputText value="Comment: " />
                            <p:inplace editor="true">
                                <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{accountManagedBean.saveAccount}" update="account" />
                                <p:inputText value="#{accountManagedBean.account.comment}"/>  
                            </p:inplace>  
                        </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>  
</h:body>
```

Problem is in saving edited information. I set breakpoint on method saveAccount and try to change values on page. After changing field value on page the program paused on breakpoint and I can see object which is saving to DB - there are old values (which were extracted from db). And on page old values are too (it's reasonable, because "old" account was updated). I use primefaces 3.0.RC2. May be problem is in ajax attribute "event" (I use "save", but in Primefaces users guide I didn't found other variants for such situation). Please help me with my problem.

Comment: I can't modify account fields and save object to DB, because after editing fields (on page) in account object nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve my problem using commandButton.

```
<h:form>
                        <p:panel id="account">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="column" cellpadding="5">  
                                <h:outputText value="Balance: " />
                                <p:inplace editor="true">
                                    <p:ajax event="save" onsuccess="saveAccount.enable();"/>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{accountManagedBean.account.balance}" required="true"/>  
                                </p:inplace>

                                <h:outputText value="Credit limit: " />
                                <p:inplace editor="true" >
                                    <p:ajax event="save" onsuccess="saveAccount.enable();"/>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{accountManagedBean.account.creditLimit}" required="true"/>  
                                </p:inplace>

                                <h:outputText value="Comment: " />
                                <p:inplace editor="true">
                                    <p:ajax event="save" onsuccess="saveAccount.enable();"/>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{accountManagedBean.account.comment}"/>  
                                </p:inplace>

                                <p:commandButton title="Save account changes" value="Save" widgetVar="saveAccount" action="#{accountManagedBean.saveAccount}" oncomplete="saveAccount.disable();" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>

                        <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {saveAccount.disable();});</script>

                    </h:form>
```

Small changes in managed bean:

```
 public void saveAccount() {
       accountController.update(account);
       // extract info for page
       // extractAccount();
    }
```

Explenation. I create commandButton with title "Save", which is disable when page is loaded. After editing one or more account values on page the button is enabled by code:

```
<p:ajax event="save" onsuccess="saveAccount.enable();"/>
```

After pushing "save" button it is disabled - i use attribute oncomplete:

```
oncomplete="saveAccount.disable();"
```

There were [problems with commandButton attribute disable](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17129), so I simple jQuery code, which make button disabled aftet loading page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {saveAccount.disable();});</script>
```

But the question about problem with saving inline values to DB is still actual.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm running Primefaces 4 and JSF 2.2 but I can't get this component to save when you click the default save button. For some reason the backing bean method is never called, which is really weird because the cancel method is called all the time. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your miss `h:form` element. Every action, which is send to server (e.g. ajax) must be placed inside `form` element. See http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyKeyEvents.jsf

Comment: I think this is careless oversimplification of the code snippet. OP explicitly mentioned that values are been saved. This is impossible without a `<h:form>`.

Comment: Thanks - although this is probably not an answer to original question, it helped me in my case. The value in inplace tag wasn't saved without `<h:form>`